# NoClassDefFoundError after upgrading Kotlin from 1.2.31 to 1.2.41/1.2.50

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: L**/**/**/**/**/SomeFragment$sam$io_reactivex_functions_Consumer$0;
```

The stack trace points to a function reference in this code snippet

```
disposables += state.filter { it == IDLE }
    .subscribe({...}, Timber::e)
```

Comment: have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @RajasekaranM nope, I just replaced method references with lambdas for now

Comment: okay did you get the error on specific android version(below android 7)? I'm also getting one error like this but it's resolved when turn off the instant run.

Comment: @RajasekaranM I haven't tried it on anything other than emulator v.26

Comment: okay @Alexander thanks

Comment: Have you tried with later versions (3.2.0-alpha versions) of the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably the following Kotlin Bug: [KT-24825](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24825)

Seems to be fixed in 1.2.60 (build-1.2.60-eap-42).
Maybe you could [test the EAP](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-1-2-60-early-access-preview/8282) (as soon as it is released).
Otherwise you should report a bug to the [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

**Update 2018-07-11**
[Kotlin 1.2.60 RC (build-1.2.60-eap-44)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.2.60-eap-44) has been released (incl. the fix for [KT-24825](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24825)). Could you please check, if it fixes your issue?

Comment: Maybe you could try again, now that 1.2.60 has been released... I'm still relativly  sure, that your problem was caused by KT-24825...